# Blazor click button only once

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am working on a Blazor WebAssembly project. Clients can create an order by clicking a button "**Create Order**".

The problem is when the user clicks the button multiple times, the system creates multiple orders with the same data (same products, same order number,
etc).

So, what is the best practice to prevent the user from creating multiple orders?

Comment: Maybe [disable the button after it is clicked?](https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazor/components/how-to-disable-hide-a-button-as-soon-as-it-is-clicked-in-blazor)

Answer (score 4):

An easy way would be to let the button be disabled once the order is being processed:

`Index.razor`:

```html
@page "/"

<button 
  @onclick="@this.ProcessOrder" 
  disabled="@this.OrderIsBeingProcessed">

  Click me!
</button>
```

The code-behind, `Index.razor.cs`:

```cs
public partial class Index
{
  private bool OrderIsBeingProcessed = false;
  
  private async Task ProcessOrder()
  {
    this.OrderIsBeingProcessed = true;
    
    // TODO: process order
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    
    this.OrderIsBeingProcessed = false;
  }
}
```

Note that this is just a (simple) demo how to disable a button, not a fool-proof way for you to guard against duplicate entries in your database.

Comment: In case of connection failure or another type of error, how do you know whether the order wasn't really saved? In case of retry you can create a duplicate, too.

Comment: @Kubus that is for the OP to guard against, this is just a quick demo how to disable a button. I updated my answer to make it clear.

Comment: thank you! I added an example, hopefully a fault tolerant one. In this way there shouldn't be duplicates and the customer will not be billed multiple times.

Comment: if you don't have a lot of processing in the button and it returns faster than the users double click speed then this method won't work - for some applications it may work out better to save the time of last process and compare to now and don't accept any subsequent clicks within a second or so

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you are using a Http Post and it is not idempotent. A unique client Id should help you in these cases. This order.ClientOrderId can be checked server side (in your data store). In case that it has already been stored it is a duplicate.

You can also disable the button, while you receive a response from the server.

Unique index will assure that duplicated order posts will not be saved in case of network failures etc or during retries.

POCO:

```
  [Index(nameof(ClientOrderId), IsUnique = true)]
  public record Order
  {
    public int Id { get; init; }

    public string ClientOrderId { get; init; }
  }
```

Blazor component:

```
<button class="btn btn-info" disabled="@IsSaving" @onclick="@(async () => await SaveAsync())">Save</button>
```

```
    using System.Net.Http;

    public bool IsSaving { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    private IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory { get; init; }

    private async Task SaveAsync()
    {
      IsSaving = true;

      var order = new Order
      {
        ClientOrderId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
      };

      try
      {

        using var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

        await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("Orders", order).ConfigureAwait(false);
      }
      catch (Exception exception)
      {
        //add retry logic
      }
      finally
      {
        IsSaving = false;
      }
    }
```

Web API controller Post method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(Order order)
    {
      var existingOrder = repository.Entities.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.ClientOrderId == order.ClientOrderId);

      if(existingOrder)
        return CreatedAtAction(actionName, new { id = existingOrder.Id }, existingOrder);

      repository.Add(order);

      await repository.SaveChangesAsync();

      var actionName = nameof(Post);

      return CreatedAtAction(actionName, new { id = order.Id }, order);
    }
```

Comment: This approach can be also applied in WinUI, WPF etc. not only in Blazor (WASM)

Answer (score 1):

> So, what is the best practice to prevent the user from creating multiple orders?

The best practice is to redesign your dataflow here. When an order is created you should either move to another page or clear your order input form.

When you clear the form, the next click should fail because there are required fields missing.